# Analysis of statistical differences between two data sets

Tags: statistical-significance, dataset, differences

I would appreciate if you could suggest what tests (on STATA) I could use to check the following:
I have data from the world bank on BMI in a certain country (nationwide);
I went on a field to collect data of a specific population within that country;
Now I want to check whether the data on BMI I collected is significantly different from the nationwide dataset or is it representative of the country's population. Statistically speaking, what do I need to look into? Variation, distribution, differences in means, etc.? What tests do I use?
Thanks.